# How do I run SSI in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to configure my website on a live server such that the default error_404.php page provided by CI3 is replaced by a custom error page that is of type .shtml, and uses SSI functionality (set vars and includes). I've made a controller and placed my .shtml files into the views folder and I successfully redirect to the error404.shtml page, but the web page is just blank. I've checked the browser console and no error logs appear. I've tried making an .htaccess file in the root directory (same level as index.php) and adding an "+Options Includes" line there, but SSI still cannot be read. Is SSI possible in CodeIgniter? I know in the server side that SSI works because all PHP sites load the error page except the ones created using CodeIgniter.

This is how I load the shtml:

```
<?php

// Error controller
// This controller is used to manage the errors (404)
class Errors extends CI_Controller 
{

    // Main controller for the contact form
    public function error404()
    {
        // Create your custom controller

        // Display page
        $this->load->view('errors/error404.shtml');
    }
}
```

This is what error404.shtml looks like:

```
<!--#set var="code" value="404" -->
<!--#set var="reason" value="Page Not Found" -->
<!--#set var="msg" value="Error" -->
<!--#set var="msg2" value="The page you are looking for does not exist." -->
<!--#set var="favicon" value="a.ico" -->
<!--#set var="logo" value="logo.png" -->
<!--#set var="tagline" value="" -->
<!--#set var="ogimage" value="ogimage.jpg" -->

<!--#include virtual="template.shtml" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, instead of using $this->load->view('errors/error404.shtml') in my Errors controller I used redirect('path/to/error404.shtml') and added $this->load->helper('url') before the redirect line.